# What does rest().post("/{path}/*") mean in a Camel route?

Tags: apache-camel

What does rest().post(**"/{path}/*"**) mean in a Camel route? Is {path} a special value? I can't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

its a path variable. This value stores in header. It will be easier to explain with an example.

```
rest("/contact").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).get("/{id}").to("direct:search-by-id");
```

this endoint triggered when u call this urls.

host:port/contact/12

host:port/contact/13

host:port/contact/14

..etc

You can access this value with this method

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  String id = exchange.getIn().getHeader("id", String.class);

}
```

Comment: Could you rewrite this using {path}?

Comment: {path} than can get any value . path a custom name u can write mypath , yourpath etc. in example this is id